# How to click an element within an iframe

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

Currently I am trying to click the "entry-level" link in an iframe, for this website:https://a127-jobs.nyc.gov/index_new.html?category=CAS

Unfortunately, the url does not change if I click entry level, so therefore I am forced to automate.

I am not sure what to do, if the problem is that I have entered the wrong iframe? there seems to be only one, but I could be wrong.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

#webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/Users/alexandrubordei/Desktop/geckodriver")

#get the website
driver.get ("https://a127-jobs.nyc.gov/index_new.html?category=CAS")

time.sleep(10)

#switch to iframe
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")

driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[0])

time.sleep(10)

#click element "entry level"
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ti_S13"]').click()
```

When I run my code everything seems to function, except the link is not clicked. My search results are not narrowed.

However I do not get any errors. I get an error as:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: first try this `count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ti_S13"]').click() ` print `len(count)`. If it is zero, that means either there's no elements with the used locator.

Answer (score 0):

you have to click the `a` element inside that ID

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ti_S13"]/a').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as **entry-level** as the the desired elements are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://a127-jobs.nyc.gov/index_new.html?category=CAS")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='ptifrmtgtframe' and @name='TargetContent']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Entry-Level"))).click()
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: entry_level]

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Thank you I will try this out, however I am curious: I am using Firefox as my web driver as I had some issues with Chrome. Is there anything major that I would have to change in the code you provided to do this?

Comment: This solution should work cross browser and cross platform. In-case of _Firefox_ you simply need to take out the `ChromeOptions` parts. However I have updated my answer as per your specifications.

Comment: Ahhahaha, well just wait because I might just be on here everyday with a new question 